# Ubuntu 16.04 bad password or options login

Tags: login

I'm very new to Linux.  I installed the OS on Sunday and everything worked well including accepting the password I created when I installed the software.

Now, two days later, when the login asks for my password I get the message "bad password or options".

I tried all the answers I could find on this site as well as searching for solutions on google and youtube.  So far, no success. Can anyone provide a clear answer to this problem or provide a tech support number?

Comment: Please don't expect us to guess what "all the answers [you] could find" etc. means. You have to describe in detail what steps you have tried and why you think they have failed i.e. what you expected to happen and what happened instead. Otherwise, if you had thoroughly searched and really tried all available suggestions, there would be nothing more to do here, because we also normally can't magically draw solutions out of our hats. Furthermore, this site aims to build a knowledge base in Q&A format from which everyone can profit, therefore we do not offer private off-site support here.

Comment: Is it possible that you had CAPS LOCK on when you typed your password initially? or that you might have capitalized a certain character when you first did it?

Comment: Can you please also confirm the exact wording of the error message? I don't recall ever seeing "*. . . or options*", it could give us a clue as to what's wrong

Comment: Yes it was a password issue all along, thank's for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except in extremely rare circumstances, when a login fails, it is because the password that was entered is not the correct password for that username on that computer.

Common reason for this is: typing the wrong password, a keyboard problem, caps lock on, wrong username / password combination, trying to log on to the wrong machine.

On systems such as Ubuntu that support file system encryption, make sure you are entering the decrypt password (and not your username password) if that's the password prompt you are responding to. Depending on how the system was built, this password may be different from the current, valid password for your user login account.  This also applies to passwords to unlock key rings and so on as well.

In short, one needs to provide a current, valid, correct password for the authentication prompt being presented.

Since you say you are new to Linux (although the above facts are true irrespective of operating system) and since you say your installation is less than 48 hours old, it is pretty much guaranteed that the password you are entering does not match the password you specified when you created that login account two days ago.

Experienced systems administrators employ hardened, best practice schemes for managing username passwords (typically for root or administrative access) for the numerous machines that they manage.  You might consider reading up on that and selecting a scheme that works for you.  In the meantime, as a new user, when building a new computer, you should probably write down ALL the passwords you specified when building your system and keep that piece of paper or notebook handy until such time as you come up with a more robust, sustainable password management process.  And of course don't forget to update the entries when you change any of the the passwords / passphrases.

Comment: I have it figured out, It's always the simple solution, I was typing in the wrong password,when asked for the sda5_crypt i was typing in the other password which was created on install which i'm guessing is like the administrator password on windows. I guess the hard drive is encrypted upon initial login for security. Thanks for the help and quick responses.As of now i have Ubuntu 16.04.3 working pretty good and am enjoying it

Comment: Glad to hear you are back up and running.  Since my answer correctly answered your question, you might consider accepting it so that it can help others who encounter similar situations in the future.  I've made a slight update in my answer to address the decrypt password issue.

Comment: Yes I will and thanks again for the help but how do i accept the answer.

Comment: Ok again i'm a noob here i discovered the checkmark above to accept the answer.